# How for loop works? And what is wrong with it?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I tried to make a reverse array with for loop.

```php
$arr = array('1','2','3');
```

I made it in this way. And this work perfect.

```php
for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($arr); $i < $iMax; $i++){
    $newArr[] = array_pop($arr);
}
//output  $newArr = ['3','2','1'];
```

But when I try to this in this way

**1.**

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $newArr[] = array_pop($arr);
}
```

**2.**

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i){
    $newArr[] = array_pop($arr);
}
```

**3.**

```php
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
    $newArr[] = array_pop($arr);
}
```

**4.**

```php
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); ++$i){
    $newArr[] = array_pop($arr);
}
```

All of those examples give the same output

```php
//output  $newArr = ['3','2'];
```

Somehow the for loop doesn't count the last one. But when I made a new variable `$iMax` it works perfectly. Can someone explain to me what going on here? And what's happening?

p.s. I know about the `array_reverse` function.

Comment: `0 < 3` then `1 < 2` but then `2 NOT < 1`.  echo your vars to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your control is `$i <= count($arr)`, then this will always stop when `$i` is compared against `count($arr)`.  You also always use `$i++` (or `++$i`) which will always increments the counter.

You also remove an item in the loop with `array_pop()`, so for each time round the loop, `count($arr)` is evaluated and will actually reduce for each loop.

This is why your first version works...

```
for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($arr); $i < $iMax; $i++){
```

as `$iMax` is set at the start of the loop only.